# Answers disappeared when migrating to Code Review

Tags: support, migrated-questions

My answers to questions

[Handling various types of nodes when traversing a DOM tree](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10273/java-help-in-refactoring-switch-case-code)

and [Merge sort on an Integer class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10276/how-to-do-merge-sort-on-integer-class-in-java/)

disapperared during migration. I had to answer the second one again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I migrated both questions and performed the deletions.

Before we migrate questions to other Stack Exchange sites, as a courtesy to those communities, we perform cleanup on the questions.

Usually, this means that answers that aren't answers are deleted, or converted to comments.

In your specific case, you provided the following "answer" on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832000/how-to-do-merge-sort-on-integer-class-in-java?noredirect=1:

> [It is possible to implement it without having to create new arrays
>   all over and copying them. Everything can be done on the original
>   array, the merge operation will require an n-long buffer. That should
>   improve it significantly.
>
>
>   I am currently on mobile, I will try to post some code later.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832750/50776)

(Note the above was 13 hours ago at the time this was originally written, probably 12 when I moved it, and nothing had been done to elaborate on the answer)

And the following on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832081/java-help-in-refactoring-switch-case-code?noredirect=1:

> [Apart from deleting some empty lines, the code cannot be made much
>   shorter. Every case has fairly different code, you don't repeat
>   yourself, so there is nothing to coalesce.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832311/50776)

The first answer is not an answer, it's more of a comment.  It could be argued that the second answer might be a legitimate answer, but it reads more like a comment as well.

When migrating, we tend to err on the side of caution, because if you don't have an account registered on the target site, then the answer is associated with an anonymous account (note, when you sign into that site, it will be associated with you again).

However, when a moderator on the target site receives the question, if the answer is attached to an anonymous account and they feel it should be a comment, then they *can't* convert the answer into a comment (it's restricted by the system).

So in the interest of preserving content, while not migrating crap, answers such as that are converted to comments (if they have any value) and the moderator on the other side isn't handcuffed into keeping content that should be there in another form.

If you notice, I did the same for [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832189/50776) before shipping it over, as it was just asking more questions of the user, and that's a comment.  If that user didn't have a registered account, then the answer couldn't be converted into a comment and the poster of the question might not see it, update it, etc.

Comment: OK I take it. Althought the first answer was more like "I know how to do it, just wait until I get home, I post it." (which happened now), the second answer was an opinion to a question that can not be answered with definitive "yes" or "no", as was demonstrated by a discussion on one of the other answers. Both answers were of maybe speculative value, so I understand it. I was just confused why I did not receive any notification about that? All I received was that "my answer was migrated to Code Review". When I go there, my answers are gone.

Comment: @JakubZaverka Well, they're comments now, the mods there might have deleted them.  If you want a notification, you could put a feature request in (like an inbox), but I don't know how that would work, as you don't get notifications on deleted answers currently.

Comment: You should not have posted that as an answer. *I'll answer your question later,* is not an answer.

Comment: I see that now. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers were deleted by a moderator **before** the questions were migrated.

Comment: Then why I got no notification about moderator deletion, but I got notification about migration?

Comment: @JakubZaverka - Don't know.